# How to experimentally create an atom in a superposition of ground and excited states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, superposition, cavity-qed

For Quantum Computing we use atoms in superposed states, but how do we physically create them?

Comment: *Every* state can be written as a superposition of other states, so the question, as written, is non-sensical.

Comment: All quantum mechanical systems are always in a superposition of states. It can't be any other way because of thermodynamics. Even if you attempt to measure a pure state (e.g. a state localized at $x$), you are merely preparing a narrow range of superpositions because of the inevitable uncertainty relation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question is about creating superpositions of eigenstates of the atomic Hamiltonian, one can do this by shining coherent electromagnetic radiation at the frequency $\omega$, such that $E = \hbar \omega$ is the energy difference between the two atomic states. This causes [Rabi oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle), so that the quantum state oscillates between the ground and excited state over time. The [Rabi frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_frequency) of this oscillation $\Omega$ is fixed by the induced dipole moment of the atom and the intensity of the driving field. If the system starts in the state $\lvert 0\rangle$, and then you apply the radiation for a time $t = \pi/(2\Omega)$, the atom ends up in the state $\lvert 0\rangle + \lvert 1\rangle$.